# Always process outermost file extension (and strip extensions along the way)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a bunch of different source files in my static HTML blog. The outermost extensions explain the format to be processed next.

**Example:** Source file `article.html.md.gz` (with target `article.html`) should be processed by `gunzip`, then by my markdown processor.

Further details:

- The order of the extensions may vary
- Sometimes an extension is not used (`article.html.gz`)
- I know how to process all different extensions
- I know that the final form is always `article.html`

Ideally I would have liked to just write rules as follows:

```
...

all-articles: $(ALL_HTML_FILES)

%: %.gz
    gunzip ...

%: %.md
    markdown ...

%: %.zip
    unzip ...
```

And let `make` figure out the path to take based on the sequence of extensions.

From the documentation however, I understand that there are constraints on match-all rules, and the above is not possible.

What's the best way forward? Can `make` handle this situation at all?

<sup>Extensions are made up examples. My actual source files make more sense :-)</sup>

Comment: How many extensions could the file have at most?

Comment: Four I think. Maybe 5 in the future. I process articles for markdown, syntax highlighting, html prettifying, templating and opt in for each processor by adding the corresponding extension to the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on holiday so I'll bite.

I'm not a fan of pattern rules, they are too restricted and yet too arbitrary at the same time for my tastes. You can achieve what you want quite nicely in pure make:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

all: # Default target

files := a.html.md.gz b.html.gz

cmds<.gz> = gzip -d <$< >$@
cmds<.md> = mdtool $< -o $@

define rule-text # 1:suffix 2:basename
  $(if $(filter undefined,$(flavor cmds<$1>)),$(error Cannot handle $1 files: [$2$1]))
  $2: $2$1 ; $(value cmds<$1>)
  all: $2
endef

emit-rule = $(eval $(call rule-text,$1,$2))# 1:suffix 2:basename
emit-hierachy = $(if $(suffix $2),$(call emit-rule,$1,$2)$(call emit-hierachy,$(suffix $2),$(basename $2)))# 1:suffix 2:basename
emit-rules = $(foreach _,$1,$(call emit-hierachy,$(suffix $_),$(basename $_)))# 1:list of source files

$(call emit-rules,${files})

.PHONY: all
all: ; : $@ Success
```

The key here is to set `$files` to your list of files.
This list is then passed to *emit-rules*.
*emit-rules* passes each file one-at-a-time to *emit-hierachy*.

*emit-hierachy* strips off each extension in turn,
generates the appropriate *make* syntax, which it passes to `$(eval …)`.
*emit-hierachy* carries on until the file has only one extension left.

Thus `a.html.md.gz` becomes this *make* syntax:

```
a.html.md: a.html.md.gz ; gunzip <$< >$@
a.html: a.html.md ; mdtool $< -o $@
all: a.html
```

Similarly, `b.html.gz` becomes:

```
b.html: b.html.gz ; gunzip <$< >$@
all: b.html
```

Neato, or what?

If you give *emit-rules* a file with an unrecognised extension (`c.html.pp` say),
you get a *compile-time* error:

```
1:20: *** Cannot handle .pp files: [c.html.pp].  Stop.
```

Compile-time? Yeah, before any shell commands are run.

You can tell *make* how to handle `.pp` files by defining `cmds<.pp>` :-)

For extra points it's also parallel safe. So you can use `-j9` on your 8 CPU laptop, and `-j33` on your 32 CPU workstation. Modern life eh?

Comment: Yeah, that's nice. You basically generate the whole make file (result is without pattern rules) before processing.

Comment: Yep, it's a lovely pattern IMHO. Seems to work well everywhere, avoiding all of _make_'s smelly bits. It's less restrictive, and less arbitrary :-)

Comment: I've upvoted (obviously), but honestly it feels a bit hacky. In a "normal" make file I can easily understand the structure (dependencies and how files will be processed). I guess it's clear here too, with the `cmds<...>` syntax, but in a completely different way than what I'm used to. Could be because I'm only a week in in my make endeavor. Also, "too restricted and yet too arbitrary at the same time" -- Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Not seen around often yes, I'd agree. But hacky? no. Pretty robust and industrial strength I'd call it. I've used it in some pretty large build systems. Being able to throw in some decent early asserts using `$(error …)` is worth price of entry alone.

Comment: A small follow up: in `rule-text` it seems it adds all intermediate files as a dependency for `all`. Could I put `all: $(HTML_FILES)` outside (where `HTML_FILES` is the list of final targets) and have make automatically remove the intermediate files for me?

Comment: Yep. Personally though I would leave the intermediate files around, much like the way you leave `.o` files in a C project etc. This allows _make_ to incrementally update just the files you have edited. After all, _make_ is about culling work. Maybe in different build folder if you are deploying straight to a website.

Comment: Hmm.. That's probably a drawback with this approach unfortunately. All intermediate files are mentioned explicitly in rules. Intermediate files derived by make itself are automatically deleted, and unless the original source is changed, the intermediate files doesn't need to be rebuilt. (10.4  Chains of Implicit Rules). So either I'll have to keep the intermediate files (but in a separate directory, because my current target directory is the actual distribution) or they will be rebuilt every time, which is obviously bad.

Comment: @aioobe You can still force these files to become intermediate with `.INTERMEDIATE: $2$1` and exclude them from `all` target to prevent auto-build, sort of `$(if $(filter %.html,$2),all: $2)`.

Comment: Ooh, I had actually misunderstood how make works. I thought `.INTERMEDIATE` files actually had to be recreated. Just tested it and it seems they don't. Thanks for making me aware!

Comment: @aioobe And this after you've just referenced the relevant topic from manual (10.4): .INTERMEDIATE: recreated only if needed, auto-deleted; .SECONDARY: recreated only if needed, not auto-deleted (obviously, .INTERMEDIATE: is the default for all implicitly "chained" targets). Yet I admit, everyone hates reading manuals thoroughly ;-)

Comment: Ooh⁽²⁾ I have never before found a need for .INTERMEDIATE. In cases like this where the intermediates are really cheap it looks like a win. Ta for that @Matt